# how to use youtube_player_iframe package in flutter?

Tags: flutter

When I use `youtube_player_iframe` package I am getting and error that is "A platform implementation for `webview_flutter` has not been set. Please ensure that an implementation of `WebViewPlatform` has been set to `WebViewPlatform.instance` before use. For unit testing, `WebViewPlatform.instance` can be set with your own test implementation.

> 'package:webview_flutter_platform_interface/src/platform_webview_controller.dart':
> platform_webview_controller.dart:1
> Failed assertion: line 25 pos 7: 'WebViewPlatform.instance != null'".

Can you help me to solve this problem.

When I use `youtube_player_iframe` package it should output youtube videos.
I hope you will be solve this issue.